# How to load GeoTIFF using Geotools?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools

I'm having trouble to load a GeoTIFF file using Geotools (never used it before).
What I've tried so far:

```
File koppenClassificationTif = new File("mongodb-repository/src/main/resources/land_shallow_topo_2048.tif");    
GeoTiffFormat format = new GeoTiffFormat();
Hints hints = new Hints(Hints.FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER, Boolean.TRUE);
GeoTiffReader reader = format.getReader(koppenClassificationTif, hints);
```

The GeoTiffFormat could not be initialized because of `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javax.measure.Unit javax.measure.Unit.multiply(java.lang.Number)'`. My .m2 repository contain 2 versions javax/measure/unit-api but I don't see why this would be a problem.

I've also tried to directly use `GeoTiffReader reader = new GeoTiffReader(koppenClassificationTif);` which throw this exception:

> org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: class
> org.apache.sis.referencing.factory.GeodeticObjectFactory cannot be
> cast to class org.opengis.referencing.Factory
> (org.apache.sis.referencing.factory.GeodeticObjectFactory and
> org.opengis.referencing.Factory are in unnamed module of loader 'app')

I'm using newly released 25.0 but I've been experiencing the same issue using 24.2

```xml
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geojsondatastore</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-coverage</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-opengis</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-geotiff</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
        <artifactId>gt-main</artifactId>
        <version>${geotools.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo-alt</id>
        <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<properties>
    <geotools.version>25.0</geotools.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Can you add the dependencies from your `pom.xml` file to your question please

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be providing an implementation of the referencing module, see the [GeoTools FAQ](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/referencing/faq.html) for more details, but adding `gt-epsg-hsql` should solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't solve my issue. The issue is due to apacheSIS and geotoolkt already present in the dependendy tree sharing older version of some dependencies with geotools.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to make the two toolkits work together

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `gt-geotiff` version 26.0 having conflicting dependencies with another package. In my case I could resolve it by explicitly loading a newer version of `unit-api` in the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
    <artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

You can also exclude the older dependency by adding

```
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.measure</groupId>
        <artifactId>unit-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

to the `<dependency>` section of its package, just to be sure.

However, the cleaner way to solve such problems is to have both packages depend on the same GeoTools version.